# cPanel App runs on Python2 instead of Python3

Tags: python, cpanel, passenger, wsgi

I have a VPS Hosting in cPanel, and a Flask-App.
I followed the instructions of [How to install WSGI Application in cPanel](https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/how-to-install-a-python-wsgi-application/).

Everything is working fine, when I run the application using the terminal, but when I open the App URL, it shows the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 369, in <module>
    app_module = load_app()
  File "/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 76, in load_app
    return imp.load_source('passenger_wsgi', startup_file)
  File "/home/qsemh/Maidan/passenger_wsgi.py", line 8, in <module>
    wsgi = imp.load_source('wsgi', 'wsgi.py')
  File "wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flaskr import create_app
  File "/home/qsemh/Maidan/flaskr/__init__.py", line 133
    print(f"Validate {len(users)} Users At {current_time}")
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So I've decided to create a simpler app in order to detect the issue, the app is as following :

**passenger_wsgi.py**

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from flask import Flask

application = Flask(__name__)

application.route("/")
def index():
    return sys.version
```

When I run this simple Application Using the URL it shows the following as a respond :

```
2.7.5 (default, Apr 2 2020, 13:16:51) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
```

even though I've used the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python3` at the start of the file, and when I run it using the terminal, it works as if it using python3.

I've tried changing the shebang to the following formats :

`#!/usr/bin/python3`

`#!/usr/bin/env 'python3'`

but they gave the same result.

What is the problem here, and How can I solve it?

Comment: Solely run `/usr/bin/python3` to see if it works fine with Python3.

Comment: Your first error is because the code uses f-strings which were only introduced with Python 3.6.

Comment: Yes, my whole project is dependent on Python3.6, that's why I used the shebang to specify python3. 

I've tried /usr/bin/python3 it works fine in the terminal, but not when I run the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the Correct approach to solve this issue;

Basically, I only needed to add the following lines at the beginning of my **passenger_wsgi.py** file :

```py
import os
INTERP = "/usr/bin/python3"
if sys.executable != INTERP: os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)
```

so the final result would be :

**passenger_wsgi.py**

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import os

# Solution
INTERP = "/usr/bin/python3"
if sys.executable != INTERP: os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)

from flask import Flask

application = Flask(__name__)

application.route("/")
def index():
    return sys.version
```

and the respond is correctly as I intended in the first place:

```
3.6.8 (default, Apr  2 2020, 13:34:55) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer might be for some cPanel users. My cPanel is using passenger and wsgi, and even though my cPanel Python application is set to use python 3.9. it was running 2.7.5. Worse, it set all the 2.7 folders in the path.

So I ended up with this helper script called from
`passenger_wsgi.py`. I'm moved all the code out of this file into an import because this file may get blown away and re-created in some cases. It's not safe to rely on code in this file surviving. It's an auto generated file.

Put `set_python_environment.py` file in the same directory as `passenger_wsgi.py`

**set_python_environment.py**

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

# insert these lines into passenger_wsgi.py if that file is rebuilt:
# import set_python_environment
# set_python_environment.upgrade_python()

import sys
import os

def upgrade_python():
    try:
            python_interpreter = "/home/username/virtualenv/YourApplicationPath/3.9/bin/python3.9_bin"
        if sys.executable != python_interpreter: 
            print('switching from ' + sys.version + ' to ' + python_interpreter + '...')
    
            print('directory: ' + os.path.dirname(__file__))
            print('file: ' + __file__)
            print('arg 0: ' + sys.argv[0])
    
            # rebuild the env path variable
            print('old system path:\n' + "\n".join(str(x) for x in sys.path))
            print('\n')
            for x in sys.path:
                sys.path.remove(x)
    
            sys.path.append('/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts')
            # App 3956 output: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyzor-1.0.0-py2.7.egg
            # App 3956 output: /usr/lib64/python27.zip
            # App 3956 output: /usr/lib64/python2.7
            sys.path.append('/home/username/virtualenv/YourApplicationPath/3.9/lib64/python3.9')
            # App 3956 output: /usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2
            # App 3956 output: /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk
            # App 3956 output: /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old
            # App 3956 output: /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload
            # App 3956 output: /home/username/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
            # App 3956 output: /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
            sys.path.append('/home/username/virtualenv/YourApplicationPath/3.9/lib64/python3.9/site-packages')
            # App 3956 output: /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0
            # App 3956 output: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
            sys.path.append('/home/username/virtualenv/YourApplicationPath/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages')
            sys.path.append('/home/username/virtualenv/YourApplicationPath/3.9/bin')
            print('new system path:\n' + "\n".join(str(x) for x in sys.path))
            print('\n')
            
            os.execl(python_interpreter, python_interpreter, *sys.argv)
        else:
            print('...continuing with ' + sys.executable)

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

**Modified passenger_wsgi.py**

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import sys
import os
import imp

import set_python_environment
set_python_environment.upgrade_python()

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))
wsgi = imp.load_source('wsgi', 'app.py')
application = wsgi.app
```

In order to get the right path, I typed `whereis python` in the ssh environment after running the `source` command given on the python application page, to find the location of all the python versions, and the one ending in `bin` turned out to be the one which actually works.